# Two duplicated <h1> tags and one hidden

Tags: seo, html, css, hidden-text

Is that bad for SEO?

```html
<h1 class="responsive-hidden">This is my title</h1>
<h1 class="hidden responsive-show">This is my title</h1>
```

Comment: Usually, yes. Not only H1 duplication, but hidden elements too. Which aim is it implemented for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, only one H1.
But there's an easy solution, which has it's own flaws (you could get very weird titles in SEO results!):

```
<h1>
    <span class="responsive-hidden">This is my title</span>
    <span class="hidden responsive-show">This is my title</span>
</h1>
```

*This is not a perfect solution! This is perfect for less importent elements in your page, but not so much for titles.*

---

If this is because of too long strings:

```
h1{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

*This will visually cut of the string to the max of the container, placing 3 dots in the end like this...*

Answer (score 0):

H1 can be used for main heading, and as per search spiders, they recommends to use only one h1 tag per page. And certainly it will affect your SEO.

Say for example, have you seen multiple titles for a single book? If yes, then don't you think it will confuse readers about the content? If not, then how can you imagine same thing for your own website?

thanks
sunil